# Perl: How do I add encoding to PAR packed archive

Tags: windows, perl, activeperl, par

The following program:

```
use Encode qw(:all);

my @list = Encode->encodings();
print join("\n", @list);
```

gives different results if I run script as .pl or as executable, created by `pp.bat` (ActiveState Perl is used)
If I run `a.exe`, created by `pp.bat` the list of available encodings is very short. How do I add encodings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add the modules directly in your code.

```
use Encode qw(:all);

use Encode::Byte;
use Encode::CN;
use Encode::JP;
use Encode::KR;
use Encode::TW;

my @list = Encode->encodings();
print join("\n", @list);
```

Answer (score 4):

Do `perldoc Encode::Supported` to figure out which module implements the encoding you want.  Then tell `pp` to include that module, either by using the `-M` command-line option, or by adding the appropriate `use` statement to your script.

For example, if you need the `iso-8859-15` encoding, that's provided by [`Encode::Byte`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Encode%3a%3aByte).  So you'd do `pp.bat -M Encode::Byte script.pl`, or add `use Encode::Byte` to script.pl.